# Given two points $P$ and $Q$ on a fundamental parallelogram, construct an elliptic function with simple poles at $P, Q$ by contour integral of $\wp$

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals, elliptic-functions, meromorphic-functions

We know that every elliptic functions can be written as a rational function of $\wp$ and $\wp'$, where $\wp$ is the Weierstrass p function.. However, I am wondering how, given two arbitrary points $P$ and $Q$ on the fundamental parallelogram, we can build an elliptic function that has simple poles at $P$ and $Q$ using the function $\wp$. My professor was mentioning how we could use line integrals based on the $\wp$ function, but I couldn't keep up with his argument.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the answer given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818844/doubly-periodic-meromorphic-function-with-prescribed-poles-and-zeros?rq=1 and the script linked within the comments.